# Nginx equivalent of UseCanonicalName (external name/port)

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have nginx running behind a front-end proxy, so while nginx is listening on port 8080, clients must actually connect to port 80.

This means that if a client requests a URL corresponding to a directory, but the final slash is missing, they receive a 301 redirection to the wrong location.

Simplified configuration:

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    root /srv/www/html;
    autoindex on;
}
```

Assume that `/srv/www/html/foo` is a directory.  If I then run `curl -I http://localhost:8080/foo`, I receive:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Tue, 18 Jun 2019 20:22:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Location: http://localhost:8080/foo/
Connection: keep-alive
```

when what I want to see is:

```
...
Location: http://localhost/foo/
...
```

(i.e., the location to which clients are redirected has a different port number than the one on which nginx actually receives the connection.)

(I don't particularly care whether nginx uses the hostname from the `Host` header or the hostname specified by `server_name` in this case.)

With Apache, this can be done by setting `UseCanonicalName`.  How can this be done with Nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [`port_in_redirect`](https://nginx.org/r/port_in_redirect) directive.

```
port_in_redirect off;
```